# UIButton position not changing -

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UIButton whose frame is defined on allocation. This button is added as a subview to the tableFooterView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.tableView = UITableView declaration...


  self.checkButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){30, 30, 260, 42}];

  [self.tableView.tableFooterView addSubview:self.checkButton];
  self.checkButton.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x,self.checkButton.frame.origin.y);
}
```

The button's x position is not updated. Any idea whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Where do you add the UIButton? maybe you can show us a little bit more code. maybe you are also going to add some content to the UIButton. you should also try to use CGRectMake for defining a new rect.

Comment: its added inside the viewdidload

Comment: The final x value will depend on the width of the tableFooterView at the time of asking for its center, and where it is positioned. Are you doing this in viewWillAppear so that layout has already occured and the frame sizes you are basing calculations on are correct. If doing this in viewDidLoad, the frames will probably not be correctly sized? Really you should do the addition in viewDidLoad but do the layout in layoutSubViews.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are adding your checkButton to your tableFooterView, so do you want to center the checkButton within the tableFooterView or the "self.view"?

If you want to center it within the tableFooterView I believe you should set the checkButton's center to it's center.

Try something like this:

```
self.checkButton.center = CGPointMake(self.tableView.tableFooterView.center.x,self.checkButton.frame.origin.y);
[self.tableView.tableFooterView addSubview:self.checkButton];
```

Although you may want to create a new UIView, add the button to the center of that and then add it to the tableFooterView. It would be a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that with new Xcode and layout system the frame structure not work.

If layout system is enable on the xib it's can be the reason of your problem.

Comment: yes good catch! it is enabled. Will setting a constraint help?

Comment: A good tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: If you are using AutoLayout then the frame is pretty much irrelevant, and the system generated constraints will move it to some bizarre and wrong place. You should indeed add constraints for size and for x/y position.